# Jquery confusion - why does my hyperlink stop working

Tags: jquery

I found someone's voting system using jquery and wanted to incorporate it into my site.  Unfortunately I want it to detect if the user has already voted and display either the vote-up or vote-down button (and link) based on this.

It works fine - apart from when I dynamically change the vote button, ie. if I vote-down an item, I change the icon to be vote-up but when I click the vote-up icon the hyperlink action isn't being triggered.  Is there something I need to do to "wire it back up"?  Note: that I've just implemented this logic on vote-down, vote-up I haven't changed yet, so it currently clears out the voting buttons. This will be fixed.

In case this is important to know - this is in a .net/mvc application.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            function onChange(newPageValue) {
                UpdateStories(newPageValue);
            }

            $(function() {
            $("a.vote_up").click(function() {
                //get the id
                var theId = $(this).attr('id').replace('vote_', '');

                // show the spinner
                $(this).parent().html("<img src='content/images/spinner.gif'/>");

                //fadeout the vote-count 
                $("span#votes_count_" + theId).fadeOut("fast");

                //the main ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { action: "vote_up", id: $(this).attr("id")}, 
                    url: "@Url.Action("ProcessVote", "Vote")",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $("span#votes_count_" + theId).html(msg);
                        // fadein the vote count
                        $("span#votes_count_" + theId).fadeIn();
                        // remove the spinner
                        $("span#vote_buttons_" + theId).html('');
                    }
                });

            });
        });

        $(function() {
            $("a.vote_down").click(function() {
                //get the id
                var theId = $(this).attr('id').replace('vote_', '');

                // show the spinner
                $(this).parent().html("<img src='content/images/spinner.gif'/>");

                //fadeout the vote-count 
                $("span#votes_count_" + theId).fadeOut("fast");

                //the main ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { action: "vote_down", id: $(this).attr("id")}, 
                    url: "@Url.Action("ProcessVote", "Vote")",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $("span#votes_count_" + theId).html(msg);
                        // fadein the vote count
                        $("span#votes_count_" + theId).fadeIn();
                        // remove the spinner
                        var votelink = "<a href='javascript:;' class='vote_up' id='vote_" + theId + "'></a>";
                        $("span#vote_buttons_" + theId).html(votelink);
                    }
                });

            });
        });

});
    </script>
```

the part of the html/mvc view that references this is:

```
@foreach (var story in Model.UserStories)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@story["FormattedID"]
                </td>
                <td>@story["Name"]
                </td>
                <td>@Html.Raw(story["Description"])
                </td>
                <td>@story["TaskEstimateTotal"]
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class='votes_count' id='votes_count_@story["FormattedID"]'>@story["VoteCount"]</span> votes
    <br/>
                    <span class='vote_buttons' id='vote_buttons_@story["FormattedID"]'>
                         @if (story["Voted"])
                         {
                             <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_down' id='vote_@story["FormattedID"]'></a>
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_up' id='vote_@story["FormattedID"]'></a>
                         }
                    </span>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

So my logic works fine normally - apart from when I dynamically put the voting button into the html placeholder, then it no longer triggers the event that it needs to.

Edit - I did try moving the functions outside of the document ready function but that doesn't fix the issue either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only register a click event with the current elements on the page

```
$("a.vote_up").click(function() {
```

what you should do, if you want to ensure that dynamic elements are covered, is to use `on`.

```
$("body").on("click",'a.vote_up',function(){
```

which will delegate this event to all current and future anchor elements with class vote_up.

Comment: Awesome thanks - that works :) (it was good to get an explanation why too!)